# Loading new HTML into sidebar without reloading entire sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712920/updating-content-in-a-google-apps-script-sidebar-without-reloading-the-sidebar) and I am still stuck trying to find a solution.

I'm trying to create a UI flow in a Google Sheets sidebar application. Right now the only way for me to load in new HTML into the sidebar is to regenerate the sidebar entirely with this code:

```
function getNextPage() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
  .setTitle('page');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}
```

How do I get my sidebar to load in a new HTML page without loading a new sidebar entirely?

Comment: `google.script.run` and in your success handler, create the new HTML. Review the many questions and answers about how to do that with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987108/7215091):

Comment: Is changing existing CSS properties from display:none to display:full the only way to do this?

Comment: @Jordan changing  the main div's  innerHtml is another way. Most SPA(Single page applications) do just that.