# How to update Sidebar in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am coding an application for Google Sheets and when searching for duplicates in a sheet I want to inform the user. I was thinking of using Sidebar to do so. But the issue is that the content do Sidebar is always overwritten. I did search the net but did not find any simple solution for Google Sheet application.

I guess I can use an variable that I would always update but what if want to update Sidebar anywhere in a complex GAS application?

Also I do not like that the Sidebar disappears

```
function testSidebar(){
  var text = "<p> New duplicate on the row";
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(text)
      .setWidth(250)
      .setHeight(300);

  for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){

    Utilities.sleep(2000);

    if (isOdd(i)){
      text += "<BR>- "+i;
      htmlOutput = HtmlService
          .createHtmlOutput(text+'</p>')
          .setWidth(250)
          .setHeight(300);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could set up an onChange() trigger, that would (re)open the sidebar every time you want to update the user.  But it will, indeed, make the sidebar disappear then reapper with the updated content.

Comment: What data do you want to show to the user? What do you mean by `the content do Sidebar is always overwritten`? When is this overwritten, and by what?

Comment: I would like to show content of a "duplicate cell" that would be ideally clickable so it would take the user to the cell so they can fix the "duplicate issue".  `always overwritten` is equivalent to setValue() but I am looking for something like appendRow()

Comment: Have you considered polling from the clientside? And just updating sections of the sidebar like you would a website.

Comment: Sidebars like any dialog are user event driven.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a sidebar project, you need to also add a HTML file (Sidebar.html):

```
const MAX_SHEET_CELLS = 5000000;

 function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Extras')
       .addItem('Open Sheet Sizer', 'showSidebar')
   .addToUi(); 
}

/**
* function to show sidebar
*/
function showSidebar() {
 
  // create sidebar with HTML Service
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar').setTitle('Sheet Sizer');
 
// add sidebar to spreadsheet UI
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

/**
* Get size data for a given sheet url
*/
function auditSheet(sheet) {
 
  // get spreadsheet object
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
  // get sheet name
  const name = sheet.getName();
 
  // get current sheet dimensions
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  const totalCells = maxRows * maxCols;
 
  // put variables into object
  const sheetSize = {
    name: name,
    rows: maxRows,
    cols: maxCols,
    total: totalCells
  }
 
  // return object to function that called it
  return sheetSize;
 
}

/**
* Audits all Sheets and passes full data back to sidebar
*/
function auditAllSheets() {
 
  // get spreadsheet object
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
 
  // declare variables
  let output = '';
  let grandTotal = 0;
 
  // loop over sheets and get data for each
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
 
    // get sheet results for the sheet
    const results = auditSheet(sheet);
     
    // create output string from results
    output = output + '<br><hr><br>Sheet: ' + results.name +
      '<br>Row count: ' + results.rows + 
      '<br>Column count: ' + results.cols +
      '<br>Total cells: ' + results.total + '<br>';
 
    // add results to grand total
    grandTotal = grandTotal + results.total;
 
  });
 
  // add grand total calculation to the output string
  output = output + '<br><hr><br>' + 
    'You have used ' + ((grandTotal / 5000000)*100).toFixed(2) + '% of your 5 million cell limit.';
 
  // pass results back to sidebar
  return output;
 
}
```

Here is HTML for Sidebar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <!-- Add CSS code to format the sidebar from google stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="button" value="Get Sheet Size" onclick="getSheetSize()" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div id="results"></div>  
  </div>
 <script>
 function getSheetSize() {
  //google.script.run.auditSheet();
  //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).auditSheet();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).auditAllSheets();

 }

 function displayResults(results) {
  // display results in sidebar
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
}

 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example is overly complicated, doesn't explain what the main point is, and doesn't answer the OP's question, which was how to update the sidebar without reloading it. Anyway, the question is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712920/updating-content-in-a-google-apps-script-sidebar-without-reloading-the-sidebar) that has a good answer; please vote to close it.